# Replace private final static in grails service for test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have a service:

```
class VideoService{
    private static final int MAX = 2000
    ...
}
```

How can I change MAX value for test?

**Update:**
without changing service, because i'm writing tests for legacy code, so don't want to change the service itself.

Comment: That's not possible and make little sense from a test point of view... the system will never have a value different to 2000 so why do you want to test that situation?

Comment: If achieve this MAX an exception should be thrown. I don't want to run heavy calculations in test 2000 times.

Comment: Change the assignment to be something based on the environment? I can post an example as an answer if you like.

Comment: Don't really want to make it too complex

Answer (score 2):

This assumes you are using a recent version of Grails. Pretty simple really.

```
import grails.util.Environment 
...
class VideoBatcherService{
    private static final int MAX = ((Environment.current == Environment.TEST) ? 20 : 2000)
    ...
}
```

**Update:** Since your property is private, static and final, you aren't going to be able to modify this for the duration of the test. Changing the source is the only option.